# Cross platform rich text in C#

Tags: c#, rtf

I come from a world (iOS and OSX) where saving a rich text string (NSAttributedString) to a file is easy (NSAttributedString can serialise itself as RTF or HTML etc.)

I'm now porting my app to Windows/C# and trying to figure out how to load/save RTF (so that my apps can share a file format)

It looks like I need to create a control (RichTextBox) in order to import RTF - which is OK for testing, but I need to read in thousands of rich text snippets so this is (probably) going to be a bit of a bottleneck.

How is this type of cross platform rich text format best achieved? I'm starting to think I will need to copy the .docx approach and create XML with textRun elements etc? This strikes me as a problem that must have been solved already - but google is not forthcoming!!

Thanks

Comment: Probably relying on html is more reasonable. But when you can read and write rtf format in both platfroms, what else do you need? What's the exact problem?